# Moving items to a nested LinearLayout is breaking my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to move elements, like changeTextView and daysLowTextView from the outermost RelativeLayout to the nested LinearLayout elements labeled col1, col2, col3, and col4, but my app will fail when it opens. I have removed all LinearLayout positioning as well. Any suggestions?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:stretchColumns="yes"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/center" 
    android:layout_width="1dp" 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topRowLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enterSymbolTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stock_symbol"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/stockSymbolEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enterStockSymbolButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enter_stock_symbol"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/companyNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topRowLinearLayout"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center"
    android:text="Company Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/yahooWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/daysLowTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stock_days_low"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yearLowTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stock_year_low"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/daysRangeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/days_range"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yearHighTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stock_year_high"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/changeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/daysHighTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stock_days_high"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastTradePriceOnlyTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/companyNameTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/companyNameTextView"
    android:text="@string/last_trade_price_only"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<!-- Begin 2 columns of data -->

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_above="@id/yahooWebView">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/col1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/col2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1">



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/col3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/col4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- end columns of data -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `my app will fail when it opens.` - do you think this is useful?  How does it fail?  What happens?  Any messages?  Any errors?  Any logs?

Comment: It was crashing on startup somewhere. Turns out the problem fixes if I clean the project before running it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to clean the project for some reason, and then it fixed itself.